# enlarge contour plot values on the line

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to know if there is a way to enlarge the values on the line in a contour plot. Attached after the code is a link to a contour plot like mine, there are values on the line and I would like to enlarge those numerical values on the contour line.

I enlarged the chart so all the axis and title shrunk, but I managed to enlarge the text for the axis and title. Now I am just having issues enlarging the values on the contour lines themselves. Attached below is a portion of the code I wrote.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20), dpi=400)
contour_graph = plt.contour(R,h_diam,keff_array)
plt.xlabel('Diameter (cm)', size = 20)
plt.ylabel('Height/Diameter', size = 20)
plt.title('Multiplication Factor for Different Deminsions', size = 40)
plt.xticks(size = 20)
plt.yticks(size = 20)
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.ylim(0,2)
plt.clabel(contour_graph)
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('contourplotratioVdiam.png')
```

https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdoxdrum.files.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F04%2Fvelocity-add.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdoxdrum.wordpress.com%2F2010%2F04%2F11%2Fcontour-plot-in-sage-and-matplotlib%2F&docid=pyXslh9eixfe-M&tbnid=8AyQEBR6HwVqYM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjB28HyopbjAhWNQc0KHcAVBgcQMwipASg6MDo..i&w=600&h=370&bih=754&biw=1536&q=contour%20plot%20python&ved=0ahUKEwjB28HyopbjAhWNQc0KHcAVBgcQMwipASg6MDo&iact=mrc&uact=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`clabel`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html) option accepts `fontsize` as a parameter to control the size of contour labels. From the docs:

> clabel(cs, [levels,] **kwargs)
>
> Adds labels to line contours in cs, where cs is a ContourSet object returned by contour().

**Parameters:**

> fontsize : string or float, optional
>   Size in points or relative size e.g., 'smaller', 'x-large'. See Text.set_size for accepted string values.

So in your case, you can use

```
plt.clabel(contour_graph, fontsize=24)
```